# update partial view ajax with no action result

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor, partial-views

So I have a very long function in C#.
My form contains a partial view that displays a string. simple.
Once the form is submitted, the controller fires the long function.
What I try to do is display in that partial view a text explaining how the process is going.
But I don't know how to make that ajax call to refresh without stopping my function.
Here is what I have:

Partial:

```
@model System.String
    Performing: @Model.ToString()
```

Main View:

```
<div  id="divLoading" style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; position: fixed; right: 0px;
    top: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color: #666666; z-index: 30001;
    opacity: .8; filter: alpha(opacity=70);display:none">
    <p style="position: absolute; top: 30%; left: 45%; color: White;">
        Saving, please wait... <img src="../../Content/images/ajax-loading.gif">
    </p>
    <p style="position: absolute; top: 37%; left: 45%; color: White;">
        @Html.Partial("_ProgressList", completedProgress);
    </p>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateInput(false)]
public ActionResult longFunction(FormCollection collection)
{
    PartialView("_Partial", response); //Update here but continue execution
    ...
    ...
}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: That's not how HTTP works.  Consider using Signalr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be doing something like a realtime update to the client as some function finishes executing. SignalR is a good candidate to opt for.

Here is a sample dummy program which sends updates to the client. You may replace the `Thread.Sleep` part with calls to your sub methods and calulate the percentage with some algorithm. This program is to give you an idea. This is not the optimal solution!

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DoIt()
{
    var context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<IssuesHub>();
    Thread.Sleep(3000);
    context.Clients.All.updateProgress(new { Status = "10 %" });
    Thread.Sleep(3000);
    context.Clients.All.updateProgress(new { Status = "50 %" });
    Thread.Sleep(3000);
    context.Clients.All.updateProgress(new { Status = "60 %" });

    return Json(new { Status = "100%" });
}
```

And in the client

```
$(function () {
    var progress = $("#progress");
    var chat = $.connection.issuesHub;       
    chat.client.updateProgress = function (result) {
        progress.html(result.Status);
    };                
    $.connection.hub.start();

  $("#someSubmitButton").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.post("@Url.Action("DoIt","Home")");
  });
});
```